# How to set the global value of % in python

Tags: python, string, constants

You can insert variables into a string easier like this:

```
print("I like %s a lot!"% spam)
```

I would like to be able to say something like:

```
% = spam
```

And never have to deal with spam again as long as I have % were I want it in the string.

like this:

```
% = spam
print("I like %s")
print("Do you like %s?")
print("I like %s a lot.")
```

Is there a way to set % to a global constant so you don't have to keep adding that little % spam thing at the end? I mean, if you are going to be printing a lot of strings with spam in them, it doesn't make sense to keep having to type out the same stuff.

Comment: No, but you can use a global search&replace in your code editor.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  I've given an answer based on my best guess, but it would help if you can show an example of what you actually want to do.

Comment: @BrenBarn thanks for the effort- I will edit my question and see if I can't make myself more clear.

Comment: Fun fact: `%` is the modulus operator. Strings just implement a very special `__mod__`. You could literally do `"I like %s a lot!".__mod__(spam)"` And it'd work.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Ooh, snarky! Are you saying that if I did "I like %s a lot!".__mod__(spam)" once, whenever I use a string with "%s" in it, it would automatically set the value of "%s" to spam?

Comment: Nope, I'm saying that python won't let you override the modulus operator anytime soon :P

Comment: I don't get why this question is so much downvoted though. I just started learning python, coming from java and others, and as I understand it, you can actually set True = False. So who knows what is possible with this crazy language :)

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Bummer... Oh well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In your question, are you intending the results to be `"I like spam!"` and so on?  If so, that would be `"I like %s!" % "spam"` (with spam in quotes).  The way you have it, `spam` is a variable, but you never assign any value to it, so it's not clear what you intend it to be.

Comment: @BrenBarn oops! No, I was expecting it to be clear that spam is a variable. Sorry¯\(°_o)/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to pre-substitute the value into the string, just do that and save the substituted string to print later.

```
message = "I like %s a lot!" % spam
# do whatever
print(message)
```

This is my best guess at what your question means.  `%` is not a real "variable" that you can set a value to independent of the string.  Rather the "%s" in the string is replaced with whatever you replace it with at the time you do `"...%s..." % blah`.  So if you want to keep a certain replaced value, you can do that whenever you like as shown above.

Based on your edit, an alternative is to write your own function that substitutes in what you want, then use that function instead of `print`.  Something like:

```
def spamify(message):
    print(message % spam)
```

Then you can do

```
spam = "blah"
spamify("I like %s!")
spamify("Do you like %s?")

spam = "other stuff"
spamify("I like %s!")
spamify("Do you like %s?")
```

and so on.